# JavaScript performance: simple key search in object vs value search in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, set

I need to emulate [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) in JavaScript — i.e. variable that is able to answer question "do I contain *x*?".

Performance of insertion/deletion doesn't matter. Order doesn't matter. And it isn't [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

There are two  ways to implement it:

1. Using regular array with value search:

   ```
   var set = [17, 22, 34];
   if (set.indexOf(x)!=-1) ...;
   ```

   - 1a. Using [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) (e.g. [Int32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array)), when possible:

     ```
     var set = Int32Array.of(17, 22, 34);
     if (set.indexOf(x)!=-1) ...;
     ```
2. Using object with key search:

   ```
   var set = {17: true, 22: true, 34: true};
   if (set[x]) ...;
   ```

Theoretically object key search should be much faster (depending on how they implemented it in JS engine, it should be either *O(log(n))*, or *O(1)* — vs *O(n)* on array value search). However, is this a case in JavaScript (where access to object member may require multiple lookups) — especially on small sets with dozens of items? Assuming that values in set are quite simple (either integers, or short strings).

**Resume.** I want to know: what minimum amount of set items is required to make object key search faster than array value search in case of: (1) values are integers; (2) values are short strings — in modern (2015/2016) web-browsers?

<sub>I understand that I can perform measurements myself, but it seems to be irrational to make every developer measure the same things — so I put this question here in case somebody have done it.</sub>

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=object+key+array+indexof+site:jsperf.com

Comment: Check out [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737850/in-js-which-is-faster-objects-in-operator-or-arrays-indexof).

Comment: @Andreas, the problem with this site is that it doesn't publish results (it would be much better if I could see results of other users with specified dates/other info; it probably will take less time for writing test than for running it in different browsers). Never-the-less, **thank you**, now I see that *object key search is faster even on small sets*, at least on Firefox/Linux/64-bit. Maybe I'll write my own test later and publish it (with results) here as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was also curious about this and I have done most of these analysis using the same stack as jsPerm on NodeJS 6.3:

https://github.com/amoldavsky/js-array-indexof-vs-hashmap

The input data is array of various sizes ( 2^x where x = 0 .. 11 ) and short keys of 1 to 2 chars.

Tests are broken by insertion, lookup, and insertion + lookup.

Results are:

- lookup using Object ( basically a HashMap ) is faster from 16 elements an up
- insert is super slow for Object keys
- insert + lookup, arrays are always faster regardless of size

Duplicates in your dataset have to be considered as well...