# JavaScript associative array and Array.indexOf lookup

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

Supposed to have a 100,000 items or more array of objects, with unique ids like:

```
myObj={
  id:makeUniqueId()
  , key:"bla"
  , key2:"blabla"
}
```

and I have to put these object in ad array with unique ids by `myObj.id`, so I would do like

`objectsList.push( myObj )`

having those alternative guards:

```
if(typeof( objectsIdMap[ myObj.id ] )=="undefined" ) {
  objectsIdMap[ myObj.id ]={};
  objectsList.push( myObj );
}
```

and

```
if( objectsIdList.indexOf( myObj.id) < 0 ) {
   objectsIdList.push( myObj.id );
   objectsList.push( myObj );
}
```

Which has better performances and why? Any productive way to achieve better performances using `Set` or `Map`?

Comment: *Which has better performances and why?* Benchmarking would tell for sure.

Comment: so it's not a good SO question? not sure maybe not, 2 downvotes but don't getting the reason.

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't. Performance advice depends on many things and is very hard to get right in the general case. Specifics about your platform can make any attempt at answering correctly moot. That's why I usually suggest benchmarking the code yourself instead of attempting to guess (most probably wrongly) the "best" approach.

Comment: Ok this right, but what about JavaScript `Array` and `Object` and `.indexOf` usage / performances? This it is not related to the platform, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replies you got to the effect that the only way to really know is to benchmark it yourself are true. However, this subject has been explored before:

[In JS, which is faster: Object's "in" operator or Array's indexof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737850/in-js-which-is-faster-objects-in-operator-or-arrays-indexof)

The bottom line is that the `typeof obj[id]` method is usually faster.

Comment: Thanks this is the right answer, so this confirms as well that this is a valid SO question or better a duplicate, and I will mark like that.