# What is the difference between `var in array` and `array.indexOf(var)`?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get my head around arrays in JS. My question is; are the following two tests equivalent?

```
var test = 2;
console.log(test in [1,2,3]);
console.log([1,2,3].indexOf(test) != -1);
```

They seem to be, but then answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737850/in-js-which-is-faster-objects-in-operator-or-arrays-indexof) and the [book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) I am reading suggest that you can't do `in` on an array, only on an object. Looking for clarity. There must be a reason that people use `.indexOf(x)` (which I assume is linear time) and not `in` (which I assume is constant time).

Comment: using `in` is looking at the object keys, for an array they are number keys rather than strings. `indexOf` is looking at the values of the array for the item and returning the index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. They are completely different.

`test in [1,2,3]` checks if there is a property **named** `2` in the object. There is, it has the value `3`.

`[1,2,3].indexOf(test)` gets the first property with the **value** `2` (which is in the property named `1`)

> suggest that you can't do in on an array, only on an object

Arrays are objects. (A subclass if we want to use classical OO terminally, which doesn't really fit for a prototypal language like JS, but it gets the point across).

The array `[1, 2, 3]` is *like* an object `{ "0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3 }` (but inherits a bunch of other properties from the Array constructor).

Answer (score 4):

The first checks for an index, or if property of an object exists,

```
console.log(test in [1,2,3]);
```

and not for a value in the array, as the second is doing.

```
console.log([1,2,3].indexOf(test) != -1);
```

Comment: So if value of test was 0, the first would still return true?

Answer (score 4):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in),

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

`in` will check for keys. Its similar to `Object.keys(array).indexOf(test)`

```js
var a1 = [1,2,3];
var a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var test = 2;

console.log(test in a1)
console.log(test in a2)

// Ideal way

//ES5
console.log(a1.indexOf(test)>-1)
console.log(a2.indexOf(test)>-1)

//ES6
console.log(a1.includes(test))
console.log(a2.includes(test))
```

Answer (score 2):

> The [**in operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

Using `in` operator for an array checks of the `indices` and the `length` property - because those are the properties for an array:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(Object.keys([1, 2, 3]));
console.log('length' in [1, 2, 3]);
```

`Object.keys` : return all enumerable properties

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` : return all properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var test = 2;
var arrval= [1, 5, 2, 4];
var a = arrval.indexOf(test);
if(a>-1) console.log("Having");
else console.log("Not Having");
```

Comment: Objective of question is **`indexOf` vs `in`** and not how to solve it